# One dimensional noetherian domain $\implies $ uniqueness of primary decomposition of ideals?

Tags: commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian integral domain whose Krull dimension equals 1. Given $I\subseteq A$ any ideal, prove or give a counter example: the minimal primary decomposition of $I$ is unique.

If $I = \cap_{i=1}^n q_i = \cap_{i=1}^m Q_i,$ with $q_i,Q_i$ primary and $r(q_i)=p_i,r(Q_i)=P_i$, since $I\subseteq r(I)$, then

$$ \cap q_i \subseteq \cap P_i.$$

So, given $j$, it follows that $\cap q_i\subseteq P_j$ and therefore, since $P_j$ is prime, exists $i$ such that $q_i\subset P_j$. Now $p_i=r(q_i)$ is the smallest prime containing $q_i$, so $p_i=P_j$. Since $\{0\}$ is prime, it follows that $P_j$ is maximal and hence $p_i=P_j$.

I cant conclude anything from this...

Comment: Can you have embedded primary components?

Comment: @user26857 Since the decomposition is minimal, all $r(q_i) = p_i$ are distinct. So, no prime $p_j$ can have $p_i$ such that $p_i<p_j$, because of the maximality of each $p_i$. Thus, all the primes are isolated and the intersection of their correspondent $q_i$s is independent of the decomposition as said in Thm 4.10 of Atiyah. This is the whole $I$, so $I$ has a unique decomposition.